# Getting unable to create a constant value of type Linq error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to get data from MSSQL database throughout EF.

See the code below:

```
model.events =
            _FoxDB.DWH_EventsBasicData.Where(
                e => e.Event_StartTime >= model.StartDate && e.Event_EndTime <= model.EndDate).ToList();

model.Tps = _FoxDB.DWH_TrainingProgramsBasicData.Where(
                t => model.events.Any(e => e.EventTrainingProgram_ID.Equals(t.TrainingProgramID))).Select(t => new EntityDropDown()
                {
                    ID = t.TrainingProgramID,
                    Name = t.TrainingProgramName
                }).ToList();
```

In the first line i am getting list of events > that part works just fine, i also convert it into `ToList` so it will run locally.

Than i want to get a list of Training Programs that exist in the event collection.

I read quite few answers regarding this error and article and i still don't understand the problem.

The error: `Unable to create a constant value of type 'FoxConcept.Models.DALModels.DWH_EventBasicData'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As far as I know* this error is because you load `model.events` to memory and then try to use it at the query to the *database*. I am not sure but it should work for you:

```
model.Tps = _FoxDB.DWH_TrainingProgramsBasicData
                .AsEnumerable() // I added this
                .Where(t => 
                    model.events
                        .Any(e => e.EventTrainingProgram_ID.Equals(t.TrainingProgramID)))
                        .Select(t => new EntityDropDown()
                        {
                            ID = t.TrainingProgramID,
                            Name = t.TrainingProgramName
                        }).ToList();
```